# How to change the size of the avatar in Drupal 7?

Tags: users, media

When i visualize user avatar in Drupal 7 using this code:

```
$account = user_load(2);
print theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account));
```

The following image is generated:

```
<a href="/drupal/en/user/2" title="View user profile."><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-2-1303917742.jpg" alt="ksu's picture" title="ksu's picture"></a>
```

How can i control such parameters as size of the image, title, alt?
And how can i get rid of the link (or change the path) which is generated automatically with the image?

```
<a href="/drupal/en/user/1" title="View user profile.">...<a/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) instead.

**Update:

Example setting width/height attributes by hand (until it's resolved in Drupal core):

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
print theme('image_style', array( 'path' =>  $user->picture->uri, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '150', 'height' => '162'));
```

Remember to change your image style 'thumbnail' in this case to your desired width/height. Now that I think about it you don't necessarily need to use theme_image_style, you could just edit the image style thumbnail presets and get the desired results. If you want width/height HTML attributes, use the example above.

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain how to use it? In the link you provided it's not clear explained.

Comment: Right now the width/height attributes has still not been properly solved in Drupal 7 core: http://drupal.org/node/1129642 - For now you need to can set those attributes manually though.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my workaround:

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['user_picture_style'] = 'PRESET NAME';
$user_picture = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account));
```

To change user picture style in node template

```
/**
 * Override or insert vars into the node template.
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['user_picture'] && $vars['display_submitted']) {
    $GLOBALS['conf']['user_picture_style'] = 'PRESET NAME';
    $vars['user_picture'] = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $vars['node']));
  }
}
```

To change user picture style in comment template

```
/**
 * Override or insert vars into the comment template.
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['picture']) {
    $GLOBALS['conf']['user_picture_style'] = 'PRESET NAME';
    $vars['picture'] = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $vars['comment']));
  }
}
```

Note: To display original image use empty string as preset name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!!

global $user;
     $user_item = user_load( $user->uid );

```
 print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item ,'style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '150', 'height' => '162'));
```