# Theme user pictures in comments in drupal 7

Tags: theming, comments, media

I'm trying to set a specific style for user pictures in comments in drupal 7, but can't find how to do it.
I know there is a module for this (http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_profiles) but it's really an overkill since I just want pictures to be themed in comments, according to a style I already created in Image_cache configuration.

In comment.tpl.php, there is a `<?php print $picture; ?>` , but it's directly the html for the image, so I can't apply the theme function of image cache, for instance `theme('imagecache','size32x32', $data->users_picture);`
The $author variable is also html.

Is there a way to get the theme function to work in this comment.tpl.php file ?
Is there another way to achieve this ? Thanks !

Comment: THat might be usefull
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-avatar-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help you understand the syntax, have a look at the [`comment.tpl.php` documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.tpl.php/7), here you will find the different variables and a link to [`template_preprocess_comment()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7) where they are defined:

```
$variables['picture']   = theme_get_setting('toggle_comment_user_picture') ? 
                          theme('user_picture', array('account' => $comment)) : '';
```

So there's a theme function to render this picture: [`theme_user_picture()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_user_picture/7) which state you should have a look a the template file: [`user-picture.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-picture.tpl.php/7) which finally send you to [`template_preprocess_user_picture()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7).

There you can [override](http://drupal.org/node/341628) this function copying and pasting the original code and changing the bits and parts you want to suit your needs (put this code in your `template.php` file):

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {
  //change only the relevant part and leave the rest of the code
  //For Drupal 7 imagecache is in core so I put the correct syntax
  $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'size32x32', 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));

  //...
}
```

Have a look at the `$variables` to find a way to target comments or add a class there and use CSS as dkiscool mentionned.

NB: if you don't like browsing all the API documentation, there's a faster way, use [theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) (see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/13715/594)).

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer. I don't follow how exactly you jump from file to file until this _preprocess_ser_picture, but I'm definitely going to try to understand it, to replicate it, and to try this "theme developer" tool. So thanks again for dateiling how you got this answer.

Comment: Actually, I needed to add a few variables to get it to work: 
`function mytheme_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['account'];
  if (!empty($account->picture->uri)) {
        $filepath = $account->picture->uri;
  }
  if (isset($filepath)) {
      $alt = t("@user's picture", array('@user' => format_username($account)));
   $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'size32x32', 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
  }
}`
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's template.php

```
function yourtheme_image($variables) {
        $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
        $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

        foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

            if (isset($variables[$key])) {
                $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
            }
        }

        return '<div class="your_class"><img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' /></div>';
}
```

this will place a "your_class" around all the images on your site then in your css file you can target it as

```
. comment  .your_class {border: solid 1px red;}
```

so that it targets only images on comments

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this interesting snippet, however I wanted to modify it not with css but directly at the output. But I'llo make use of your code somewhere else...